# Dynamic type parameter for Blazor components

Tags: blazor, radzen

I want to design a common radzen data grid for multiple data types. Which means on the razor page I have common markup for radzen data grid. Record set and column definition bind to the grid dynamically. My problem is with ‘TItme’.

I need something like:

```
TItem="typeof(data.records[0])"
```

Datagrid as follows:

```
<RadzenDataGrid FilterMode="FilterMode.Simple" Data="@data.records" TItem="typeof(data.records[0])" AllowFiltering="@data.allowFiltering" AllowPaging="@data.allowPaging" AllowSorting="@data.allowSorting">       
    <Columns>
        @foreach (var colDef in data.columnDefinitions)
        {
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="typeof(data.records[0])" Property="@colDef.columnProperty" Title="@colDef.columnTitle"  />
        }            
    </Columns>           
</RadzenDataGrid>
```

Comment: Please rename the title so that it becomes more generic, e.g. "Dynamic type parameter for Blazor components".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try dynamic component in dotnet 6:

```cs
<DynamicComponent Type="@componentType" Parameters="@parameters" />

@code {
    private Type componentType = ...;
    private IDictionary<string, object> parameters = ...;
}
```

DOCS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Another option for other dotnet versions would be to try to define a render fragment directly in code (notice the line with ATTENTION comment):

```
@page "/built-content"

<h1>Build a component</h1>

<div>
    @CustomRender
</div>

<button @onclick="RenderComponent">
    Create three Pet Details components
</button>

@code {
    private RenderFragment? CustomRender { get; set; }

    private RenderFragment CreateComponent() => builder =>
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(PetDetails));
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "PetDetailsQuote", "Someone's best friend!");
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "TItem", typeof(data.records[0])); // ATTENTION
            builder.CloseComponent();
        }
    };

    private void RenderComponent()
    {
        CustomRender = CreateComponent();
    }
}
```

DOCS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: But @aleksander_si I I need to use common data grid for n number of multiple types. I cannot create sperate grids for each type and render dynamically.

Comment: My answer will also cover your requirement, please check again.